# TikZ: Drawing a curve using controls

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{1.87529 * 4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ly}{sqrt(3) * 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lx}{\d / 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\per}{1707 / 6378 * 4}

\coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (M) at (\d, 0);
\coordinate (L4) at (\Lx, \Ly);

\draw (E) -- (M);
\draw (E) -- (L4);
\draw (M) -- (L4) node[font = \scriptsize, above] {\(L_4\)};;
\draw[-latex] (E) -- (-45:2cm) node[below = .1cm, font = \scriptsize]
{\(v_r\)} coordinate (P1);
\filldraw[blue, opacity = .7] (E) circle (1cm);
\filldraw[gray, opacity = .7] (M) circle (.3cm);
\filldraw[green] (.7 * \per, 0) circle (.075cm);
\node[font = \scriptsize] at (\Lx + 2, \Ly)
{\((187529, 332900.1652, 0)\)};
\draw[dashed, thick] (E) circle (1.2cm);
\draw[dashed, thick, red] ([shift = (E)] -45:1.2cm) .. controls (3, 1)
and (-4, 5) .. (L4);

\draw let
  \p0 = (E),
  \p1 = (P1),
  \p2 = (M),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {2cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
in (E) + (\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, font = \scriptsize] at ([shift = (E)]
\n4:\n3) {\(\nu = -\frac{\pi}{4}\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I have tried constructing this curve by using `controls` in draw but it didn't quite work out.  Maybe there is a better way than this but I don't know.

So the flight path would start at the dotted circle and vector `v_r` and end at the location `L_4`.  In the Python code, I plotted the solution longer than needed.

[image]

Here is the current image but the curve I would like to add is picture below:

[image]

---

**Edit 2:**

So I have constructed a somewhat decent curve but I am hoping someone can help it look a little better still.  Also, I have changed the screen shot.  Why is the figure not centering and is skewed to the right?

Comment: Do you have a mathematical description of the curve, or do you just want something that looks like it?

Comment: I meant how precisely do you want to reproduce that within the TikZ picture?

Comment: It can't solve them (at least not as far as I know), but seeing you've solved them in Python, you could export a list of coordinates and plot those in your `tikzpicture`.

Comment: So you just want to draw a curved path that looks roughly like the second picture in your post, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the two pictures are related: I guess the blue circle is the same in both, but how does the red path from the second picture fit into the first picture? Does it have to end at a particular place? Does the path have to start out in a particular direction (in line with the arrow, perhaps)? Maybe you could include a mock-up of the final picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you draw the bounding box for your `tikzpicture` (after adding `\centering` and a test caption):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[fixed point arithmetic]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{1.87529 * 4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ly}{sqrt(3) * 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lx}{\d / 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\per}{1707 / 6378 * 4}

\coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (M) at (\d, 0);
\coordinate (L4) at (\Lx, \Ly);

\draw (E) -- (M);
\draw (E) -- (L4);
\draw (M) -- (L4) node[font = \scriptsize, above] {\(L_4\)};;
\draw[-latex] (E) -- (-45:2cm) node[below = .1cm, font = \scriptsize]
{\(v_r\)} coordinate (P1);
\filldraw[blue, opacity = .7] (E) circle (1cm);
\filldraw[gray, opacity = .7] (M) circle (.3cm);
\filldraw[green] (.7 * \per, 0) circle (.075cm);
\node[font = \scriptsize] at (\Lx + 2, \Ly)
{\((187529, 332900.1652, 0)\)};
\draw[dashed, thick] (E) circle (1.2cm);
\draw[dashed, thick, red] ([shift = (E)] -45:1.2cm) .. controls (3, 1)
and (-4, 5) .. (L4);

\draw let
  \p0 = (E),
  \p1 = (P1),
  \p2 = (M),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {2cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
in (E) + (\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, font = \scriptsize] at ([shift = (E)]
\n4:\n3) {\(\nu = -\frac{\pi}{4}\)};
\draw 
  (current bounding box.north west) 
  rectangle 
  (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

you get:

[image]

which shows that the bounding box is centered, but something is contributing to it, besides what actually appears in the drawing. Where does this contribution come from? The answer is: from one of your control points (simply place two visible elements at the coordinates used as control points and you'll see this clearly).

You could interrupt the bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[fixed point arithmetic]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{1.87529 * 4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ly}{sqrt(3) * 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lx}{\d / 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\per}{1707 / 6378 * 4}

\coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (M) at (\d, 0);
\coordinate (L4) at (\Lx, \Ly);

\draw (E) -- (M);
\draw (E) -- (L4);
\draw (M) -- (L4) node[font = \scriptsize, above] {\(L_4\)};;
\draw[-latex] (E) -- (-45:2cm) node[below = .1cm, font = \scriptsize]
{\(v_r\)} coordinate (P1);
\filldraw[blue, opacity = .7] (E) circle (1cm);
\filldraw[gray, opacity = .7] (M) circle (.3cm);
\filldraw[green] (.7 * \per, 0) circle (.075cm);
\node[font = \scriptsize] at (\Lx + 2, \Ly)
{\((187529, 332900.1652, 0)\)};
\draw[dashed, thick] (E) circle (1.2cm);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw[dashed, thick, red] ([shift = (E)] -45:1.2cm) .. controls (3, 1)
and (-4, 5) .. (L4);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw let
  \p0 = (E),
  \p1 = (P1),
  \p2 = (M),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {2cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
in (E) + (\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, font = \scriptsize] at ([shift = (E)]
\n4:\n3) {\(\nu = -\frac{\pi}{4}\)};
\draw 
  (current bounding box.north west) 
  rectangle 
  (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or choose different control points inside the bounding box; for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[fixed point arithmetic]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{1.87529 * 4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ly}{sqrt(3) * 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lx}{\d / 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\per}{1707 / 6378 * 4}

\coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (M) at (\d, 0);
\coordinate (L4) at (\Lx, \Ly);

\draw (E) -- (M);
\draw (E) -- (L4);
\draw (M) -- (L4) node[font = \scriptsize, above] {\(L_4\)};;
\draw[-latex] (E) -- (-45:2cm) node[below = .1cm, font = \scriptsize]
{\(v_r\)} coordinate (P1);
\filldraw[blue, opacity = .7] (E) circle (1cm);
\filldraw[gray, opacity = .7] (M) circle (.3cm);
\filldraw[green] (.7 * \per, 0) circle (.075cm);
\node[font = \scriptsize] at (\Lx + 2, \Ly)
{\((187529, 332900.1652, 0)\)};
\draw[dashed, thick] (E) circle (1.2cm);
\draw[dashed, thick, red] ([shift = (E)] -45:1.2cm) .. controls (3, 1)
and (-1, 5) .. (L4);

\draw let
  \p0 = (E),
  \p1 = (P1),
  \p2 = (M),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {2cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
in (E) + (\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, font = \scriptsize] at ([shift = (E)]
\n4:\n3) {\(\nu = -\frac{\pi}{4}\)};

\draw 
  (current bounding box.north west) 
  rectangle 
  (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another possibility with a modification for the curved path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[fixed point arithmetic]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{1.87529 * 4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Ly}{sqrt(3) * 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Lx}{\d / 2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\per}{1707 / 6378 * 4}

\coordinate (E) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (M) at (\d, 0);
\coordinate (L4) at (\Lx, \Ly);

\draw (E) -- (M);
\draw (E) -- (L4);
\draw (M) -- (L4) node[font = \scriptsize, above] {\(L_4\)};;
\draw[-latex] (E) -- (-45:2cm) node[below = .1cm, font = \scriptsize]
{\(v_r\)} coordinate (P1);
\filldraw[blue, opacity = .7] (E) circle (1cm);
\filldraw[gray, opacity = .7] (M) circle (.3cm);
\filldraw[green] (.7 * \per, 0) circle (.075cm);
\node[font = \scriptsize] at (\Lx + 2, \Ly)
{\((187529, 332900.1652, 0)\)};
\draw[dashed, thick] (E) circle (1.2cm);

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw[dashed, thick, red] 
  ([shift = (E)] -45:1.2cm) to[out=60,in=-60] (1.3,1.4) 
  .. controls (0.3,2.5) and (1.2,4.8) ..  
  (L4);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

\draw let
  \p0 = (E),
  \p1 = (P1),
  \p2 = (M),
  \n1 = {atan2(\x1 - \x0, \y1 - \y0)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\x2 - \x0, \y2 - \y0)},
  \n3 = {2cm},
  \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2) / 2}
in (E) + (\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3, start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2]
node[fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, font = \scriptsize] at ([shift = (E)]
\n4:\n3) {\(\nu = -\frac{\pi}{4}\)};

%\draw 
%  (current bounding box.north west) 
%  rectangle 
%  (current bounding box.south east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also do you know to better fit my curve to the simulated curve?

Comment: @dustin I added another option to my answer. You still can play with different combinations of `controls` and/or the `to[in=,out=]` syntax. However, I think I more sensible approach would be to let an external program (Geogebra, for example) calculate some coordinates for the path you want, and then use those coordinates.